# Weird behavior of hexdump on MacOS

Tags: c, bash, hexdump

I am supposed to recreate the behavior of hexdump in C and now when I (almost) finished the task, the actual hexdump command behaves weird.

When I use:

```
hexdump -C filename1 notexistingfilename2
```

the error message for the non existing file appears between the lines of the output of the first file.
like this:

```
0000c4f0  65 00 64 79 6c 64 5f 73  74 75 62 5f 62 69 6e 64  |e.dyld_stub_bind|
0000c500  65 72 00 5f 5f 64 79 6c  64 5f 70 72 69 76 61 74  |er.__dyld_privat|
hexdump: h: No such file or directory
0000c510  65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |e.......|
0000c518
```

h being the non existing file.

This wasn't the case when I used hexdump earlier today. (System is MacOS and the behavior is the same in Bash aswell as in zsh, also not using the -C flag doesn't make a difference).

Comment: I am seeing a similar behavior on windows/msys2. I would say it is because of how `stdout` and `stderr` are buffered. Not something that should concern you when reimplementing it.

Comment: You have discovered that `stdout` and `stderr` are different output streams. I think you are correct in that `hexdump` should have flushed the `stdout` buffer before opening a new file, but I would say it's a minor bug. Not even a bug, but a minor inconvenience.

Comment: ok I am just gonna write in the end like it does in tail/cat/head/...

Comment: This is not an issue with _your_ code, so clearly not a question for SO.  Unless you need to _replicate_ this behaviour in your code; in which case we'd need to see your code.

Comment: @Clifford no I didnt want to save it in a new file. I wanted hexdump to print 2 files in a row. And because the second file doesn't exist it should print the error message. When I used cat or tail this was working fine.

Comment: @jsiller I realised that and edited the comment before you posted. It is still not an SO question as it is about the behaviour of standard utility, not your code. If you need to replicate this you need to output your error messages to stderr.

Comment: It is a bit weird because standard output is usually line-buffered, if it is going to a terminal. So, if `hexdump` wrote those last two lines before it tried to open the other file, they should have appeared on the terminal first. To reproduce this behavior, you would need to either change standard output to fully buffered or write the error message for the later file before finishing the output of the earlier file.